# "with" statement in Python

Tags: python, proxy

I have a lots of class implemented in my code. Now I realise that for each method invoked for all these classes I need to add a line:

```
with service as object:
```

So I'm trying to use the Proxy pattern to automatically do the job, this is my example code

```
    class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def hello(self):
        print 'hello %s!' % (self.name)
    def __enter__(self):
        print 'Enter the function'
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print 'Exit the function'
#        
class Proxy(object):
    def __init__(self, object_a):
#        object.__setattr__(self, '_object_a', object_a)
        self._object_a = object_a

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        service = object.__getattribute__(self, '_object_a')
#        with service as service:
        result = getattr(service, name)
        return result    

if __name__=='__main__':
    a1 = A('A1')
    b = Proxy(a1)
    b.hello()
    a2 = A('A2')
    b = Proxy(a2)
    b.hello()
```

Everything works find, I have the output:

```
hello A1!
hello A2!
```

But when I uncomment the `with` statement, I have the error

```
Enter the function
Exit the function
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hnng/workspace/web/src/test.py", line 30, in <module>
    b.hello()
  File "/home/hnng/workspace/web/src/test.py", line 24, in __getattribute__
    result = getattr(service, name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hello'
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `__enter__` method is returning `None` instead of returning the object. It should read:

```
def __enter__(self):
    print 'Enter the function'
    return self
```